# Finding genome coverage using random reads

Tags: algorithm, bioinformatics, genome

Thank you for looking at my question. I am trying to solve this homework question.

> Consider the problem of sequencing genome by random reads. If G is the
>   length of the  entire sequence, L is the length of the read and n is
>   the number of reads, then coverage is defined as nL/G. Now, if we want
>   50% of the original long sequence to be covered by at least one
>   fragment, how much coverage do we need?

I read Lander-Waterman http://www.genetics.wustl.edu/bio5488/lecture_notes_2005/Lander.htm model to understand the concept. But didn't quite get how to solve this problem. I thought to consider the given 50% as probability and y as 1 (the one from Poisson distribution) and calculate lambda (that is the coverage). But I don't think I am on right track. I thought of considering y as 1 because the question says 50% of the original long sequence to be covered by atleast one fragment, which means that those bases are sequenced atleast once.

I may be wrong.

Experts can you guide me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this really a programming question? Sounds like a math issue rather.

Comment: This is what we learn in algorithms class.

Comment: I don't even understand the question either. Where do you define "fragment?"

Comment: If you can go to the link that talks about poisson distribution and its relation with genome fragments. I'm sorry, I didn't know how to explain all the terms in short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not off so far. As I read it y=1 means that the bases are read "exactly once" and not "at least once". You would need to calculate the coverage under the probability of 0.5 for P(y=1) + P(y=2) + ... which is equal to ...

Comment: btw I removed the GeneticAlgorithm tag since this doesn't have anything to do with GAs.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it as a continuous problem (as in, n is large and L is much smaller than G), and assume the placement of each read is completely random, the likelihood that each additional read is wasted is proportional to the existing coverage.  This leads to the following math:

```
d(coverage)/d(n) = (L/G) * (1 - coverage)
```

As this is homework, I will leave the solution as an exercise for the reader.  (I would like to point out, though, that this is a rare case of actually using calculus to solve a CS problem 8^)

---

Solving the above equation, starting with coverage=0 at n=0, yields:

```
   ln(1 - coverage) = - (L/G) * n
-> coverage = 1 - exp(- (L/G) * n)
```

As a reality check, note that this is what you should expect to see: if your sampling is truly random, the uncovered part of G should decay exponentially, like a radioactive element.

Comment: Maybe my doubt is a bit silly, but are you taking differentiation of coverage with respect to n?

Comment: Its alright. Can you please elaborate it a bit more, to be honest I tried getting it but I am unable to do so.